# Using PHP to insert text on PDF file without extra software

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a PDF file that my users can fill out their name using a html form, and that name would be inserted on a specific location in the file.

What classes are best for achieving this, without installing extra server side software?

Comment: Why do you believe that PHP classes are not extra server side software?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/fpdi) for this task: It allows you to import pages of existing documents into a structure which you can re-use with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org). This way you are able to re-create the document while adding additional content to it.

If you want to modify an existing document (FPDI has some [limitations](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/) because of its internal structure) you may checkout the [SetaPDF-Stamper](http://www.setasign.com/stamper) component (not free). It allows you to add new content to an existing document without re-creating it from scratch (as you have to do with FPDI).